# Visual Studio 2010 DataCompare table comparison

Tags: visual-studio-2010, data-comparison

In Visual Studio 2010 do you have the ability to compare the data of a database between 2 databases. I wanted to use this to copy data from one database to another. These databases have the exact same structure. But when I do a compare I see only 65 tables showing up in de DataCompare view in VS2010 but I have 66 tables in the database.

The next step was to find out which table not was showing up. The name of this table is 'CMS_PluginInstanceRouteParams'. This table is also present in both databases which I also have checked. The structure of this table is:

[image: Structure of CMS_PluginInstanceRouteParams]
The FK is a relation to the PK of the CMS_PluginInstance table. The CMS_PluginInstance does show up in the Data Comparison window and the data is also compared and copied.

I also couldn't find a dialog or option where I can enter some table names to ignore.

Does anyone of you know why this table is not showing up in the list of tables in the Data Comparison window and why the data of this table not is compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d84a758e-79ea-4170-8807-7f8bdec98de1/:

*Tables and views must meet two criteria to appear in the listing:*

*First, the schemas of the objects must match between the source and target database.*

*Second, only tables and views that have a primary key or a unique key appear in the list.*

Answer (score 1):

The DataCompare tool of VS2010 only compares tables that have unique keys.  It is most likely that this missing table does not have a unique key.  As for transferring data the best bet would be to use SQL Server Management Studios Import and Export tools.  You should have no trouble finding guides online.