# How to create NO primary key table with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

My goal is to create a no PK table in the database (I will never use it for ORM). I only need to create it, that's all.

I know it is possible to create a no PK table with NHibernate from this stack overflow question [Why is NHibernate creating a table without primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755079/why-is-nhibernate-creating-a-table-without-primary-key) But I need it to work in Java not .Net

Here is what works. It has PK, but I don't need it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
<class entity-name="testtablenopi">
<id name="id"
            type="long"
            column="ID">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
</id>

<property name='xarxint'  column='xarxint'    type='int' precision='11' scale='0'/>
<property name='xarxbig_decimal'  column='xarxbig_decimal'    type='big_decimal'  precision='17' scale='2'/>
</class>
```

When I remove `<id/>` it doesn't work .

I tried replacing `class` with `bag` it didn't work.

How can I create a database table without a PI in hibernate?

Comment: NHibernate is a different product than Hibernate. Don't assume things about Hibernate from the behavior of NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Hibernate and all ORMs I know require a PK to be defined for an object.

You'll need to use a plain old JDBC insert statement.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use native sql. Sql flavors differ with different databases.  Create statement in oracle is different than create statement in mysql.